# Render html content inside *ngFor loop in ionic2/angular2 project

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2, ngfor

in a ionic2 project I need to render some html content inside a tag in a *ngFor loop.

here my template:

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <ion-thumbnail item-left>
            <lazy-img src="{{post.thumbnail}}"></lazy-img>
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{post.content}}</p>
        <button ion-button clear item-right (click)="viewPage(post)">View</button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

inside **post.content** i have some html tags.
how can i render it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `innerHTML`:

```
<p [innerHTML]="post.content"></p>
```

Note: if there's some potentially unsafe code in your HTML, you will have to use [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html).